# Python cx-freeze shortcut icon

Tags: python, windows-installer, cx-freeze, distutils, shortcut-file

I use cx-freeze to distrute an application by making a msi install file. In the setup.py script I specify the shortcut which needs to be placed on the desktop. However the shortcuts icon is blank. The setup.py contains the following code. What am I doing wrong?

```
import ...
....
shortcut_table = [
    ("DesktopShortcut",                                             # Shortcut
     "DesktopFolder",                                               # Directory_
     "PhotonFileEditor",                                            # Name
     "TARGETDIR",                                                   # Component_
     "[TARGETDIR]\PhotonEditor.exe",                                # Target
     None,                                                          # Arguments
     None,                                                          # Description
     None,                                                          # Hotkey
     "[TARGETDIR]photonsters.ico",                                  # Icon
     0,                                                             # IconIndex
     None,                                                          # ShowCmd
     "TARGETDIR",                                                   # WkDir
     )
]


# Now create the table dictionary
msi_data = {"Shortcut": shortcut_table}
#msi_data = {"Shortcut": shortcut_table, "Icon": icon_table}

# Change some default MSI options and specify the use of the above defined tables
bdist_msi_options = {'data': msi_data}

....
```

Comment: Not really sure.  But since it's been 2 days and no responses, have you checked that you don't need a backslash on this line? "[TARGETDIR]\photonsters.ico".  Also, the 'Icon' field is actually 'Icon_' in the Windows Installer documentation, i.e it's a foreign key into a table called 'Icon'. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/icon-table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thx, this solved my problem! A snippet of my code:

Shortcuttable:

```
shortcut_table = [
("DesktopShortcut", # Shortcut
 "DesktopFolder",   # Directory_
 "PhotonFileEditor",# Name
 "TARGETDIR",   # Component_
 "[TARGETDIR]\PhotonEditor.exe", # Target
 None,              # Arguments
 None,              # Description
 None,              # Hotkey
 "",                # Icon (Use 
 0,                 # IconIndex
 None,              # ShowCmd
 "TARGETDIR",                   # WkDir
 )
]
```

Setup:

```
setup (  name = "PhotonFileEditor",
         version = "0.1",
         author= "Photonsters",
         url="https://github.com/Photonsters",
         description = "Photon File Editor",
         options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options,"bdist_msi": bdist_msi_options},
         executables = [Executable(script="PhotonEditor.py",       
         base=base,icon="PhotonEditor.ico",)]
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you tried to:

   - add `icon` parameter to your `Executable`?
   - remove the backslash in the `Target` of your `shortcut_table`, and remove the `Icon`and `IconIndex` entries?

     ```
     import ...

     ....
     shortcut_table = [
         ("DesktopShortcut",                                             # Shortcut
          "DesktopFolder",                                               # Directory_
          "PhotonFileEditor",                                            # Name
          "TARGETDIR",                                                   # Component_
          "[TARGETDIR]PhotonEditor.exe",                                 # Target
          None,                                                          # Arguments
          None,                                                          # Description
          None,                                                          # Hotkey
          None,                                                          # Icon
          None,                                                          # IconIndex
          None,                                                          # ShowCmd
          "TARGETDIR",                                                   # WkDir
          )
     ]


     # Now create the table dictionary
     msi_data = {"Shortcut": shortcut_table}
     #msi_data = {"Shortcut": shortcut_table, "Icon": icon_table}

     # Change some default MSI options and specify the use of the above defined tables
     bdist_msi_options = {'data': msi_data}

     executables = [Executable(....,
                               icon='photonsters.ico')]

     ....

     setup(....,
           executables=executables)
     ```
2. Have you checked that the icon file `photonsters.ico` is present in the `build_dir` directory after the build step?